# Java: Is there a refactoring "pass whole entity into method instead of entity attributes" in popular IDEs?

Tags: java, ide, refactoring

I would like to refactor the following code:

```
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  register(customer.getId(), customer.getFirstname(), customer.getLastname());

  ...

  private static void register(final UUID id, final String firstname, final String lastname) {
    addNewCustomer(id, firstname, lastname);
  }
```

into

```
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  register(customer);

  ...

  private static void register(Customer customer) {
    addNewCustomer(customer.getId(), customer.getFirstname(), customer.getLastname());
  }
```

The reverse operation would be useful, too. Is there a name for this refactoring operation and is there an IDE that supports this out of the box, or via plugin?

Comment: Can you do it (in intellij) by defining an overload which takes a `Customer` (and delegates to the existing method); and then find and replace duplicates for the new overload.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, you can use Refactor->Change Signature:

[image]

You'll get a dialog with all the method's arguments:

[image]

Remove them all, add a Customer argument and click the "Use Any Var" checkbox:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't do the whole operation, e.g. move the getter calls inside the `register` method.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij:

- Define an overload for the method:

  ```
  void register(Customer customer) {
    register(customer.getId(), customer.getFirstname(), customer.getLastname());
  }
  ```
- Position the cursor over the `register` method name
- Select "Find and replace code duplicates" I'm the refactoring menu

This should identify the places which can be invoked using the new overload.

You can then inline the original method into the overload, if you so desire/have no remaining invocations of that method.